# How do I get started with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to begin using Selenium. I have downloaded the Selenium Stand Alone Server, Selenium for JAVA, and GeckoDriver. I added all of the .jar files from the Stand Alone Server and Selenium for JAVA to my buildpath in Eclipse. When I run my program, I get the follwing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    FirefoxOptions cannot be resolved to a type
    FirefoxOptions cannot be resolved to a type

    at check.Selenium_Basic.main(Selenium_Basic.java:14)
```

My code is below:

```
package check;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class Selenium_Basic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Do you guys know why this doesn't work? Is there a good step by step guide that will allow me to start using this? I have looked at many guides but I can't figure out what I've done incorrectly.

Comment: Seems you are missing required files or your build path is incorrect.

Comment: How about importing that class?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. You are missing an import statement for FirefoxOptions. You can add the below line to your code with other import statements & your code should work.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
```

Also, you don't need to use Selenium StandAlone Server. Selenium Java alone with GeckoDriver would work fine. Make sure that you are using Selenium 3.4, as its compatible with Gecko 16.

You can also check this link for complete setup related steps -

[Selenium 3.4 – Complete Guide to the latest Selenium WebDriver](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3/)